# Making inline SVG responsive in browsers without using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I've been reviewing [articles like this one](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/#svg-viewbox) which are really good, but possibly dated, and I'm wondering if any progress has been made on a simple way to make inline svg responsive while maintaining the aspect ratio?

In other words if we have svg with a 1:1 aspect ratio inside a div container, and the container shrinks from 400x400px to 200x200 px, then the view box width and height parameters double.

Comment: sure use a viewBox

Comment: Without Javascript?

Comment: Without javascript?  A demo would be great ...

Comment: before: <svg> after you use a text editor to change the markup: <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">

Comment: What happens when other are viewing the page on various devices with various sizes?  Do they also need to go in and manually change the viewbox parameters?  The end goal is for the svg to automatically shrink on small devices with small screen real estate and expand on large screens ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused about what you want. I don't know what you mean, in your question, when you talk about "view box width and height parameters double". Perhaps you are confused about how `viewBox` works.

As long as the SVG has a `viewBox` it should be responsive.

In the following example, I've put the SVG in a `div` container and animated the container size to simulate the page size changing.

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  background: linen;
  animation: scale 1s alternate infinite;
}


@keyframes scale {
  from { width: 200px; }
  to   { width: 100px; }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="gold"/>
    <rect x="10" y="50" width="20" height="50" fill="gold"/>
    <rect x="70" y="50" width="20" height="50" fill="gold"/>
    <circle cx="35" cy="45" r="5"/>
    <circle cx="65" cy="45" r="5"/>
  </svg>

</div>
```

But it could just as easily be a container that is the width of the page.  Try running the following snippet. Then click "Fullpage" and resize the browser window.:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background: linen;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="gold"/>
    <rect x="10" y="50" width="20" height="50" fill="gold"/>
    <rect x="70" y="50" width="20" height="50" fill="gold"/>
    <circle cx="35" cy="45" r="5"/>
    <circle cx="65" cy="45" r="5"/>
  </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Well THEN!  Thanks - That was eye opening.  After reviewing an angular component and some of the other documents I had convinced myself that this is a lot more difficult that it should be...but now I'm unconvinced.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to change svg with css or modify it, I suggest you to use it as an `img` element. You create an `img` and put the path to your svg in the `src`. Here's what I mean: https://codepen.io/tlemaitre/pen/PBKGOo

Comment: That's essentially the effect I'm looking for except more responsive.  In other words if the div image `container` shrinks then the inline svg also shrinks automatically.  I was hoping that perhaps browsers had worked this out by now ...

Comment: If the question is resolve thank you mark it as resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had a similar problem, I have a container that needs to be `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to keep the shape fluid on different window sizes but the image inside gets gets distorted. I've not seen any solution to this problem with or without JS, so I don't think it's possible.

Comment: You may want to look at this angular round progress component.  https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar  I'm studying how the responsive part of it works.  IIUC if you set `preserveAspectRatio=none` then the aspect ratio will not be preserved so your image will get distorted.

Comment: Hi @Ole, yes I'm aware of how the whole aspect ratio thing works, I was trying to find a way of having a clip shape that keeps the image ratio, where I could put an overflow:hidden property on the shape but this isn't possible.

Comment: There's a really good tutorial here: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/svg-viewport-and-viewbox-for-beginners--cms-30844     So for example when the viewport on the circle is set to 100x100px, the entire circle shows, but if the viewport (<svg width="50" height="50">) is set to 50x50px then only a quarter of the circle shows, and the rest is clipped...maybe you knew that ... but at least it clips the image ... probably have to control those properties with javascript though ...