# Do we gain anything from setting the SVG elements width and height to 100%?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, svg

The Angular material documentation application has an SVG Viewer that does this:

```
  inlineSvgContent(template) {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = template;

    if (this.scaleToContainer) {
      let svg = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('svg');
      svg.setAttribute('width', '100%');
      svg.setAttribute('height', '100%');
      svg.setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid meet');
    }
  }
```

IIUC all we need to do to make the SVG scale to the container is save it with the correct `viewBox` parameters [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528518/making-inline-svg-responsive-in-browsers-without-using-javascript).

This is the demo circle from the answer:

```
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="gold"/>
    <rect x="10" y="50" width="20" height="50" fill="gold"/>
    <rect x="70" y="50" width="20" height="50" fill="gold"/>
    <circle cx="35" cy="45" r="5"/>
    <circle cx="65" cy="45" r="5"/>
  </svg>
```

That circle will fit any container without setting `width=100%` and `height=100%`.

So I assume then that the reason the Angular team does it is because the want to set `width` and `height` to some fixed value for another use case?

Generally I'm just curious about the design and whether we gain benefits from it.  In other words is this a common pattern for UX developers and why?

Comment: This would be for responsiveness. See this article: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/svg-viewport-and-viewbox-for-beginners--cms-30844

Comment: Namely: `We’ll start by looking at “zooming”, which we can do with the last two viewBox parameters: width and height respectively. We’ll leave the first two parameters at 0 0 for now.

If those last two parameters have the same dimensions as the viewport, there’s no zooming in or out so nothing changes.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it might be useful, because it seems this method doesn't know how has been declared the svg element, so they are overriding these attributes so that whatever was set before doesn't prevent the responsiveness of the element.

Since this function is named `inlineSvgContent` we can assume it's a kind of sanitizer.

It's quite common (and even recommended) to make standalone svg images have absolute width and height attributes (e.g in px), so that the renderer knows how to draw it. Failing to do so, the default will be 100%, but in some cases, it's hard to understand 100% of what exactly. Having absolute width and height allows for a well known aspect ratio.

---

Now, if you were to create the element from scratch that would be pretty useless, since these are actually the default values:

```js
const svg = document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg' );

console.log( 'width', svg.width.baseVal.valueAsString ); // 100%
console.log( 'height', svg.height.baseVal.valueAsString ); // 100%
console.log( 'preserveAspectRatio', svg.preserveAspectRatio.baseVal );
// align: 6 => SVG_PRESERVEASPECTRATIO_XMIDYMID
// meetOrSlice: 1 => SVG_MEETORSLICE_MEET
// => "xMidYMid meet"
```